# Restarting a running scheduled task

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

We have a program, which we run on system startup, with the Windows Task Scheduler. The programs sometimes stops responding though and hence needs to be restarted. To keep it simple I just want to restart it at a fixed interval - say every 30 minutes - to keep it alive.

**Is there a way to restart a scheduled task at a fixed interval, even if the instance originally started, is still running?**

I have looked at *Repeat task every: (...)*, but as far as I can tell, this will just spawn a new instance and not stop the existing instance first?

[image: Edit Trigger screenshot]

Comment: The best way by far of course is to find out _why_ it stops working, and fixing the actual problem. I think the best way to answer your question is to run a script every 30 minutes (each 30 mins has its own trigger) which checks if the task is started, and if not start it. Or create a process watcher script that triggers a restart of the task whenever the process died.

Comment: It's a 3rd party program, which we are working to replace (since it sucks). But until then I need some sort of simple mitigation to the problems :-).

Comment: Maybe simply register this application as a service? when service process hangs OS can restart it automatically. From the other side it is dangerous to use (and especially as a service) an application which may hang in any unpredictable moment...

Comment: Is it possible to register any program as a service? When I Googled it, it seemed that the program had to be developed as a service (I cannot change the code of the program)? Either way, it's hopefully only for a limited time period, so it doesn't have to be a perfect solution.